# Has anyone an idea about IBM OpenWhisk and Cors settings?

Tags: node.js, cors, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

i have the following problem. When run my openWhisk function through the API gateway all is fine. Also calling it as a cross domain request works well.

But i need to call it with credentials and it seems there is no option to do this.

What i tried:

1. just enabling the API CORS setup without any headers in the function itself
2. enabling cors in the API und having CORS headers in the function as well ->the relevant headers (access-origin) in the function get overwritten!
3. disabling CORS in the API and having CORS headers in the function -> the relevant headers (access-origin) of the function get deleted

This is the code that normally should work:

```js
return {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': domain,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
        },
        body: xml
    }
```

Would be great if anyone has an idea because the support is not answering my ticket for many days now.

Thanks and best, André

Comment: Try using `wsk action update <your action> -a web-custom-options true` (see https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md#options-requests).

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but did not work for me. Also calling the function as REST-APi with .http ending just send two headers for access origin (*,'http://something')

Comment: Bluemix Support prioritizes tickets depending on the type of support that is associated with your account. There is Free, Basic, Standard, and Premium levels. Each of these levels, the ticket severity, and the targeted response time is documented at the following URL: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/support/index.html?pos=3#contacting-support

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the API management does not support fine grained configuration for CORS, it is on or of. 
And the allowed origin(s) must be set of the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample:

```
> cat t.js 
function main() {
return {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'domain',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
        },
        body: "<hi></hi>"
    }
}
```

Against Bluemix:

```
> wsk action update t t.js -a web-custom-options true --web true
ok: updated action t
```

And curling the web action

```
> curl -v https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/api/v1/web/myspace/default/t.http
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Backside-Transport: OK OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: nginx/1.11.13
< Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 14:00:40 GMT
< Content-Type: text/xml
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
<hi></hi>
```

Without the annotation:

```
> wsk action update t t.js -a web-custom-options false --web true
```

Repeating the curl will show these headers:

```
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,domain
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, DELETE, POST, PUT, HEAD, PATCH
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type,*
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```